# Issue with scanner and file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a. csv file from which I want to read and write. If there is new input, it should check if string1 already exists inside the file. String1 can contain numbers, chars and spaces.

Writing to the file is no issue at all, but when it should check if string1 exists, it works only if string1 is 1 or 2 appereantly. But string1 is going to be a string out of chars, numbers and spaces

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);                   
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(string1)) {
            // Print some error message
        }
        else{
            // write output to .csv file
            }
    }
    scanner.close();
```

I've tried changing encoding of the file, but that didn't help either..

Comment: `"abcde".contains("bc")` works but maybe you intended _any char in the search string_: `"abcde".matches(".*[ae].*")`.

Comment: How can I search any char in string when string is a variable?

Comment: `line.matches(".*[" + string1 + "].*");` basically, but some special regex characters must be handled aditionally: `-`,  `]` and such.

Comment: I don't mean any char sry, but the string itself. Like when I put 1234 it should allow input if 123, but not 1234..

Answer (score 0):

Even i was having some issue with Scanner and csv reading so I did it with BufferedReader Code:-.

```
    String inputFileName = "fileName";
    BufferedReader br ;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
        String line = br.readLine();
    }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But Scanner also works for csv , Scanner code :-

```
Scanner br;
    try {
        br = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFileName));
        String line = br.next();
    }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't help really. The scanner itself seems to work, but the filter with contain makes some issues with the special chars.. Same for BR, I've tried that some hours ago

Comment: Add all the read value in to a set and iterate the set  and write in to a file. you will not have any duplicated value.